# 'The handle is invalid' error while using ApplyTransform() in InstallerCustomActions

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I'm trying to fetch properties from a transforms file by applying the transforms to my msi file and then querying it.
I get an error only in my InstallerCustomActions project, in a standalone project the code works fine.

> Error: The handle is invalid. 
>      at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Database.ApplyTransform(String transformFile, TransformErrors errorConditionsToSuppress)

```
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
public string FetchPropertyValue(string installerFile, string transformsFile, string query)
    {
        Database msiDatabase = null;
        View view = null;

        using (msiDatabase = new Database(installerFile, DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly))
        {
            msiDatabase.ApplyTransform(transformsFile);
            string sqlQuery = query;

            view = msiDatabase.OpenView(sqlQuery);
            view.Execute(null);
            Record record = view.Fetch();

            string strResult = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                record.GetString(2);
            }
            catch { }
            return strResult;
        }
    }
```

EDIT : 
I'm trying to retrieve custom properties from the 'Property' table of the installer.
Calling this function from my Commit method

```
 public override void Commit(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Commit(savedState);

    ....

string strServer = FetchPropertyValue(installerFile,transformsFile, "Select `Property`,`Value` FROM `Property` where `Property`='Server'");
```

I tried making a copy of my installer and then tried the above function and it did not work

Comment: What kind of custom action is this (deferred, immediate, etc.)? Where is it being scheduled in the `InstallExecuteSequence`?

Comment: Are you opening your running MSI file? That might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be supported. Microsoft publishes a list of [Functions Not for Use in Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368612.aspx) that includes [`MsiOpenDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370338.aspx) and [`MsiDatabaseApplyTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370074.aspx), which in turn are the native API calls underlying `new Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Database` and `msiDatabase.ApplyTransform()`.

However, due to the remoting of DTF, I'm uncertain in exactly what context these calls occur. If the calls occur in the remote managed process, this would not explain the symptoms you encountered. If instead they occur in the native thread owned by Windows Installer, the documented limitations are relevant.

Comment: Without more context it's hard to say, but if as I suspect the transform is being applied to the current installing MSI then it's doomed because they can be applied only at command line install time. If it's another MSI file there's no reason to run the code from a custom action instead of a standalone program where it works.

Comment: @PhilDW: Agreed; I can't think of a scenario in which I would know the correct set of transforms and not know a property's value. I wonder if the original code was attempting to access properties not available in script.

Comment: They occur in the native thread. See http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/DTF/Tools/SfxCA/RemoteMsi.cpp